# Linq to XML join

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have one XML file where values are stored in category element separated by comma:

```
<Company>
<name>Test</name>
<category>Power,Water,Gas</category>
</Company>

<Company>
<name>Test2</name>
<category>Water,Gas</category>
</Company>
```

In other XML file only one value is stored in category element:

```
<Bills>
<name>Test</name>
<category>Power</category>
</Bills>

<Bills>
<name>Test2</name>
<category>Water</category>
</Bills>
```

So now i need to join these two xml files and get all Company nodes that contains category value from Bills node.

I have this query:

```
Xdocument fRoot = XDocument.Load("company.xml");
Xdocument rRoot = XDocument.Load("bills.xml");

var query = from f in fRoot.Elements("Company")
                        join r in rRoot.Elements("Bills")
                        on (string)f.Element("category").Value equals (string)r.Element("category").Value 
                        orderby(string)f.Element("name").Value
                        select new{...}
```

With this i get nothing because Company node category values are stored separated by comma, and i don't know how to split them to do JOIN on these two files.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is vague. What do you really mean by joining the files? Did you want to merge them and produce separate entries? The best way to clarify your question is to edit it and include an example of your expected output, then people will be able to help you.

Comment: as an aside, you don't need to cast `XElement.Value` to string, because it is a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
var query = from f in fRoot.Elements("Company")
    from r in rRoot.Elements("Bills")
    where ((string)f.Element("category").Value).Split(',').Contains((string)r.Element("category").Value )
    orderby(string)f.Element("name").Value
    select new new{...};
```